# Performance problems when using renderTexture-> saveToFile() and nodeGrid-> runAction() features cocos2d-x

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

In process of learning cocos2d-x I have the following questions.

Function renderTexture-> saveToFile (filename, Image :: Format :: PNG) is very slow. App literally freezes for 2-4 seconds, 
all animation hang when I call this method!
It's not normal, how to fight it?

Using the object and method nodeGrid runAction for sprites can apply different effects.
In my application I use Waves3D and ShuffleTiles. And it also causes terrible brakes (especially ShuffleTiles), and when the device is not very
productive they hang up to hardreset or the application terminates.

Can I do something wrong? Why such effects if they cause such severe problems?
Here is an example of code that terribly slow if its calls at the same time for 5-9 sprites.

```
ActionInterval * shuffle = ShuffleTiles :: create (2, Size (15, 15), 100);

nodeGrid = NodeGrid :: create ();
nodeGrid-> runAction ((Sequence *) Sequence :: create (shuffle, NULL));
```

Comment: what device? how big is the texture? It's very possible that saving a large file takes a few seconds depending on texture size and device's cpu and flash memory speed.

Comment: 1. "what device?" 
any android device of average performance (for example, Sony Xperia P) hangs for a few seconds while maintaining the texture file.

2. "how big is the texture?"
texture takes approximately half of the screen. This is a screenshot of the screen, this is the sprite, which contains the sprites.

Comment: 3. "It's very possible that saving a large file takes a few seconds depending on texture size and device's cpu and flash memory speed."
Yes, I understand what happens. But is it possible to make it more pleasant for the user to not hang the whole application?
I tried to bring it to another non-main thread, but no results.
I have a few ideas:
1.At the time of saving file to put a picture on the screen that does not animate, and thus does not hang
2.Saving a file when it is imperceptible. For example, when the application terminates or goes into the background (on applicationDidEnterBackground)

Comment: the grabbing screen contents can not be multithreaded, but the writing of the texture to disk could but only if you get the texture in a uiimage equivalent - problem being that the actual GL texture can not be accessed from a different thread and ccrendertexture code isn't prepared to be run in the background (unless this has changed in v3)